# Relation between Fubini's Theorem and the equality of mixed partial derivatives.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[image]

To solve it, there are many accounts and the procedure is extensive. I want to know what is the relation between Fubini's Theorem and the equality of mixed partial derivatives.

Comment: to prove what it is asked, it is helpful to write $F(x,y) = \int_c^y \int_a^x f(u,v)dvdu$, which is justified by Fubini.

Comment: Never post unsearchable images of text and equations.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: I understand that, but I want to know how the theorem and the equality of partial derivatives are related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you the intuition of how it works:

To begin with, Fubini's Theorem states that $F(x,y) = \int_c^y \int_a^x f(u,v)dudv = \int_a^x \int_c^y f(u,v)dvdu$, where F is a continuous function over the region R defined by $[a,b]\times[c,d]$.

We know that $F(x,y) = \int_c^y \int_a^x f(u,v)dudv = \int_a^x \int_c^y f(u,v)dvdu$.

Differentiating both sides of $F(x,y) = \int_c^y \int_a^x f(u,v)dudv$ with respect to $y$:

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y) = \int_a^x f(u,y)du$

Now with respect to x:

$\frac{\partial F^2}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y) = f(x,y)$

Differentiating both sides of $F(x,y) = \int_a^x \int_c^y f(u,v)dvdu$ with respect to $x$:

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y) = \int_c^y f(x,v)dv$.

Now, with respect to $y$:

$\frac{\partial F^2}{\partial y \partial x}(x,y) = f(x,y)$.

Therefore, $\frac{\partial F^2}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y) = \frac{\partial F^2}{\partial y \partial x}(x,y)$.

I hope I clarified a little more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that they are necessarily related, other than that there are two dummy variables being integrated up to x and y respectively, and differentiating w/r/t one gives you the other. Maybe I am misunderstanding the question.

After rereading, I think maybe the question is just asking you to differentiate w/r/t x and then y, then switch the order of the integrals, and differentiate w/r/t y and x, in that order. This will show that the order of the partials does not matter, if we assume Fubini's theorem.